# Structure for table to record events in other tables?

Tags: mariadb, schema, event

Say I have three tables:

```
people
groups
memberships
```

with the following primary keys:

```
uid
gid
uid+gid
```

I would like to record events such the creation/deletion off people/groups/memberships.  I could obviously store such events in separate extras table  for each main table, e.g.

```
events_people
events_groups
events_memberships
```

However, I wondered whether there might be a way to just use a single `events` table.  This would have the columns

```
id (PK)
date
uid
gid
info
```

whereby `uid` would be non-null for a user event, `gid` non-null for a group event, and both non-null for a membership event. `info` would contain a JSON blob of other information related to the event.

Is that a plausible way of addressing the problem or is there some other approach I should consider?

Update:

The idea of the events table is that I would be able to select events relevant to specific `uid` or `gid` or between given dates.  So it is for a fairly simple auditing.

Comment: This is clear "opinion-based question". You even have no described how do you want to use this events table... For example, my approach is a table which contains only 3 columns - uid, gid and timestamp. ID is obviously excess, the timestamp completely defines the events ordering. Info - what do you want to put into it? those which does not store in another columns yet?

Comment: Indeed I am interested in the opinions of others regarding possible alternative approaches.  At a minimum ```info``` would contain a command, such as ```add``` or ```delete```, although that might in fact warrant its own column ```command```.  In that case ```info``` might just contain less information which is not common to all events such as, say ```language```, which would be an argument of the command ```add person```, but not of ```add group```.

Comment: @Akina "*ID is obviously excess, the timestamp completely defines the events ordering.*" - Only true if there's never two events that occurred at the *same* time. But if it's possible for two events to have the same `timestamp` then the `id` column (when defined as an auto-increment identity) at least defines which of the two events were recorded first in this log table deterministically. Otherwise the data would be nondeterministic.

Comment: @J.D. This can be adjusted with timestamp accuracy. 3 fractional digits is enough in 99% of cases, 6 digits guarantees the uniqueness.

Comment: @Akina nothing stops 2 events from having the same exact timestamp to 6 digits of precision, so it doesn't *guarantee* uniqueness.

Comment: @J.D. MySQL have only one analyzer/plan builder afair. 1mks is too low for to start 2 queries parsing.